# How to automatically export Google Spreadsheet to Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

How to automatically export Excel Google Spreadsheet to Excel?

Comment: If you download the googlesheet it will automatically download as excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Just download the googlesheet from the same API, when you download it, the file is an excel spreadsheet.